# How to use loadObjectsAtResourcePath from Restkit 0.10.0 for a http post to a php script?

Tags: php, ios, post, restkit

I'm using Restkit 0.10.0 and I can't figure out how to do a http post with object mapping. This is what I have so far:

```
baseUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.whatever.com"];
RKObjectManager* objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
objectManager.acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON; 

// mapping
RKObjectMapping * userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[User class]];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"id"];
[userMapping mapKeyPath:@"g" toAttribute:@"genre"];
[[objectManager mappingProvider] addObjectMapping: userMapping];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"response"];

// post request 
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Montreal", @"Canada", @"", @"", @"", @"1", @"0", @"2", @"0", nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"c", @"co", @"lat", @"lng", @"rad", @"s", @"o", @"ageG", @"w_ageG", nil];
NSDictionary *queryParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString *getResourcePath = RKPathAppendQueryParams(@"people.php", queryParameters);

// send request and wait for answer, delegate self will map objects
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/people.php" delegate:self];
```

When I do this post, with

```
$city = $_POST['c'];
```

in the php file for example, nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: i'm exactly stuck at attempting a POST using RestKit. What I can point out is I don't think you should use `loadObjectsAtResourcePath` and instead try to use `postObject:usingBlock:` or `postObject:delegate:` method

Comment: i see. But thing is I don't want to post an object, I just want to post parameters as to get a response that will build my object. Why is this so complicated?

Comment: OK. I've got object mapping working (somewhat) for GET requests. can you post here what's the error/output RestKit is giving and also a sample of your expected json data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RKURL *rkUrl = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:baseUrl resourcePath:postString];
RKObjectLoader* loader = [[RKObjectLoader alloc] initWithURL:rkUrl mappingProvider:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider];
loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
loader.delegate = self;

loader.objectMapping = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[MyObject class]];
[loader send];
```